# How to getBean() by Name programmatically 

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring3.1

I have registered a Bean programmatically and I want to retrieve it programmatically as well but no success.

```
public void createBean(String beanName, String beanParam) {
    System.out.println("beanName=" + beanName + " beanParam=" + beanParam);
    ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextSingleton.getApplicationContext();
    StaticApplicationContext innerContext;= new StaticApplicationContext(context);
    innerContext.registerSingleton("beanName", FixSessionBean.class);
    configureBean(innerContext, beanName, beanParam);
} 

public void configureBean(ApplicationContext innerContext, String beanName, String beanParam) {
    innerContext.getBean(beanName);
    FixSessionBean fixSessionBean = (FixSessionBean) innerContext.getBean(beanName);
}
```

from my applicationContext:

```
<bean id="FixSessionBean" class="com.finbird.fixgw.beans.FixSessionBean" />
```

Here is some log evidence:

```
beanName=mm1 beanParam=mm2
2012-07-09 13:07:31,016 com.fixgw.test.TriggerBean [ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mm1' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mm1' is defined
```

any idea why it's not going well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this line

```
innerContext.registerSingleton("beanName", FixSessionBean.class);
```

registering your bean with name "beanName", not the value of the `beanName`-parameter? Perhaps you meant to use the parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass bean class name as `FixSessionBean.class` if you want to get that one, the mm1 is not defined in you appctx if that is all you posted.

Comment: But I want to retrieve a specific instance of FixSessionBean. how would I do that?

Comment: @rayman check esaj answer is that what you're looking for? that was my next guess

Comment: @rayman If you want a specific instance, why register it as singleton? --> `innerContext.registerSingleton("beanName", FixSessionBean.class);`

Comment: Pay attention that I use StaticApplicationContext. I am trying to register bean dynamically having each bean with it's own variables.